# Do ETH have its own contract address in Ethereum Chain?

Tags: etherscan

Sorry that i have a stupid question would like to ask.

As I know, each token which ride on EVM has its own contract address.
However, i am not sure native token.Such like native token (ETH), will it has its own contract address in ETH chain?

Also, if ETH by default do not have contract address on ETH chain, then how about ETH2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eth, as any other native cryptocurrency, is not governed by any smart contract, account, or address, but by the protocol itself.
New Eth is generated and rewarded to miners when they mine a block.
The same goes for ETH2.0, blocks are going to still be mined, but by randomized miners/validators based on the PoS consensus mechanism.